# "Knowledgeable about" vs. "knowledgeable on" vs. "knowledgeable in"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, in-on

When should I use each of the collocations "knowledgeable about", "knowledgeable on", and "knowledgeable in"?

Answer (score 5):

If you must use *knowledgeable*, then

*knowledgeable in*

*knowledgeable about*

are your best choices.  *Knowledgeable on* is not correct.  *On* implies that *knowledge* is a physical object that can have a physical position relative to something.  For example,  the following phrases use prepositions that commonly apply to physical objects:

*knowledgeable under*

*knowledgeable over*

*knowledgeable beside*

These phrases don't make sense.

If you remove the *-able* suffix from *knowledgeable*, the phrases can be used in the following manner:

*He has great knowledge in the field of Mathematics.*

*She possesses significant knowledge about Geology.*

*The NSA has voluminous knowledge of our calling habits.*

Removing the *-able* suffix allows you to describe the knowledge involved in a more specific manner.